# Access- calculate days between first and last fields user entered

Tags: vba, database, forms, ms-access

I have a form with two columns and two sections (pink-phase 1 and purple-phase 2). For each column within the pink section I want to calculate the total days between the first cell entered and the last cell entered. Same for the purple section.
Right now I have an equation that calculates the total days between the first and last field of each column within the sections, but I want to calculate the total days between the first field a user updated and the last field a user updated. Is this possible if so can someone please help me. Thank you!

```
For Each ctl in Me.Forms.Controls 
    If ctl.Tag = “pinkPlanned” Then
    Me.PhaseOne = Max(fieldname) - Min(fieldname) 
End If
Next ctl
```

EDIT: I figured out a code that works for me. I created a function that takes in an array and loops through the array to find the max date and min date.

```
    Function dtMinMax (ParamArray arrFields () )
```

Then within the function I use the DateDiff function to calculate the total days between the max and min date.

```
    DtMinMax = DateDiff(“d”, [dtmMin] , [dtmMax])
```

Then I call this function in my query design view, using the fields I want to loop through as my arrays.

Comment: Of course it is possible but without any information on how your form is actually structured (and no a picture from your phone does not really help) there is no way for anyone to help you.

Comment: @SunKnight0 Sorry about that! The form is a bound form. It is bound to a query I created of the table that is to be updated. In the image I posted the only fields a user can fill out are the white blank cells. The fields in pink and purple calculate and show  (for right now) the total days between the first and last field in each section. This calculation is done through a query.

Comment: What you want is difficult in query and on form. Pulling data from another record of same table is tricky. More complicated because you want "first" and "last". Review http://allenbrowne.com/subquery-01.html#AnotherRecord

Comment: You will probably have write VBA code writes the results to unbound boxes. For an actual solution you would have to post table and field names, form and text box names and their relationships. You can't just post an image and expect a solution that requires programming to come out of a crystal ball.

Comment: @SunKnight0 I added some better pictures. Does this help?

Comment: @June7 I added better pictures which might help. Everything on the form goes into one record.

Comment: Data and code should be text, not images. Query should be SQL statement as text not design view image. I agree that this will likely require a VBA custom function.

Comment: @June7 Sorry, I know you pointed this out before. I’m using my work laptop and most websites are blocked so I’m using my iPad to post.  I was thinking about writing a VBA custom function. Something that can find the first cell with data and look for the last cell with data within a section and calculate total days between the two.

Comment: Identifying what is 'first' and 'last' record is trickier than might think. Google the topic. May involve a filtered recordset sorted by maybe a date field. Then move to first and last records of recordset to pull values and set variables to calculate with.

Comment: @June7 is there a way to find the first empty field?  Or would that process be around the same? I’m googling now thank you

Comment: @June7 I just realized what I really want is to find the max and min for each column within the two sections. Is there a way to group certain controls then write a for loop? Like for  i between this group find min and max and calculate the total days between the two?

Comment: Still not clear. What does `fieldname` represent? Is this a variable? How does variable get set? If you want to pull a field name from Tag property: `Max(Me.Tag)`. But then why not just specify a field? Why would you need to loop controls? Just put expression in ControlSource. Edit question to show raw data and desired output.

Comment: @June7 the fieldname represents the name of the field where data is being entered. Editing now

Comment: @June7 I typed up the code that I ended up using and works for me. Thank you for all your help!